# Using a variable in a DOM string

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to put a variable into a dom string. I have various fields as such:

```
<input type="text" name="itemdesc1" />
<input type="text" name="itemdesc2" />
```

I want to loop through these to see if they are populated before submit. The only problem I have is that I cannot run them through a loop, because I need to put a variable into the DOM string. The variable is "i".

```
if (document.insertinv.itemdesc(variable_here).value == ''){
     // Code
}
```

Is there any specific way to do this? Preferably without adding id's to the fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the bracket notation, also I would encourage you to access your form elements in the [standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-76728479) way, accessing the [`elements`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.elements) HTMLCollection (`document.forms[x].elements[y]`):

```
var element = document.forms[0].elements['itemdesc' + i]; 
         //or document.forms['formName']...
if (element.value == ''){
  // Code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to concatenate the variable onto the dom-string:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByName('itemdesc'+i);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if ( document.getElementsByName("itemdesc"+i).value == '' ){
     //CODE
}
```

Comment: `.` is not the concatenation operator

Comment: Treby is likely a PHP programmer :) I find myself mixing up the syntax from time to time too :)

Comment: sorry man.. got carried away.. yah jonathan.. i am a php programmer

Comment: Nearly there but `getElementsByName` returns a list of matching elements, not a single element.